# Laravel status population

Tags: php, laravel, livewires

The approval of user by admin it's not populating options I made use of this

$this->statuses = $this->applicant->accountApplication->statuses()->get();
I am expecting it to populate options to accept or reject applicat

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be asking a question.  What is the question?  What has been tried so far?  Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection from view to livewire then I added in livewire in form this `<option value="accept">Accept</option>`
`<option value="reject">Reject</option>`
And it populated the options

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to populate options for user approval (accept or reject) in a web application. However, based on the code snippet you provided, it's not entirely clear what the issue might be.

The line of code you shared:

```php
$this->statuses = $this->applicant->accountApplication->statuses()->get();
```

This code is retrieving the "statuses" related to the applicant's account application. However, it doesn't directly indicate why options for user approval are not being populated.

To diagnose the issue, you should consider the following steps:

1. **Check the Data**: Verify that the data in your database is set up correctly. Ensure that there are "statuses" for the applicant's account application with the appropriate values (e.g., "accept" and "reject").
2. **Inspect Blade Template**: Check your Blade template (the view) to make sure that you are correctly iterating over the `$statuses` variable and generating the appropriate HTML for user approval options.
3. **Debugging**: Use debugging techniques to inspect the data and variables at various stages of the process. You can use `dd($this->statuses)` to see what data is being retrieved.
4. **Check the Controller/Logic**: Make sure that the logic in your controller or application service is correctly handling the request and providing the necessary data to the view.
5. **Route and Middleware**: Confirm that the routes and middleware (if any) are correctly set up and that authentication and authorization mechanisms are not preventing the options from being displayed.

If you have a specific error or behavior you are encountering, please provide more details or error messages, and I'd be happy to offer more specific guidance.

Comment: I connected to live wire from view

Comment: @can('change account application status') <form action="{{route ('account-application.change-status', $applicant->id)}}" method= "POST" class="col-md-9 m-auto><x-select id=name name="status" label="Status"  wire:model="status"> @foreach ($#

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->statuses = $this->applicant->accountApplication->statuses()->get();
```

here statuses() is the relationship defined in accountApplication model
try to call statuses like

```
$this->statuses = $this->applicant->accountApplication->statuses;
```